# How can I echo the product_name?

Tags: php

Php3:

```
function createOrder()
{

    echo $_POST['member_name']."<br/>";
    echo $_POST['member_email']."<br/>";
    echo $_POST['member_phone']."<br/>";
    echo $_POST['product_id']."<br/>";
    echo $products[[$_POST['product_id']-1]['product_name']]."<br/>";//how can i echo this row
    echo $_POST['quantity']."<br/>";
```

I can print out including member_name,email,phone,and product_id but product_name still show blank in web page

Comment: Can you show a sample of `var_dump($products)`?

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from `$_POST['product_id']`? Why not make `$products` an associative array that uses the product ID as the keys?

Comment: let me show the details

Comment: @Barmar Php1:
<label for="product_name">Pre-order product name</label>
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="
    <?php
        echo $_GET['product_id'];
    ?>
">

<h2>
    <?php
        echo $products[$_GET['product_id']-1]['product_name'];
    ?>
</h2>

Comment: @Barmar
Php2:
$products =
[
    [
        'product_id'    =>  1,
        'product_name'          =>  'cable',
        'price'         =>  20,
        'image'         =>  '6.5 - Silver.png',
        'remaining'     =>  1000
    ],
    [
        'product_id'    =>  2,
        'product_name'          =>  'cable',
        'price'         =>  20,
        'image'         =>  '7.8 - Black.png',
        'remaining'     =>  1000
    ]

Comment: Put code in the question, not comments, so you can format it properly. And what does `Php1` and `Php2` mean?

Comment: What will happen to `$products` if there are gaps in the product ID sequence?

Comment: You have an extra set of `[]`. It should be `$products[$_POST['product_id']-1]['product_name']`

Comment: You need to enable full error reporting. That should have produced a warning about a nonexistent array key.

Comment: php1 and php2 for a php document

Comment: I have no idea what that means. php1 and php2 are not standard PHP things.

Comment: Anyway, none of that is important any more. You just mistyped the array indexes, I showed how to fix the typo. The question should just be closed and deleted.

Comment: I get the answer  I need include the array list

Comment: What do you mean by that? Isn't it the same array you showed in the comment above?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code.

```
index_value = $_POST['product_id']-1;
$products[index_value]['product_name'];
```

I hope it help!